# How to Store contacts manually by passing number only

Tags: android

I have searched everywhere and tried most of the solution but it adds contact number and name automatically if i pass them from the database. But i want to pass the number only and later insert the name using system default contact manager . How can i do it ?

Comment: You get from the database exactly what you ask the database to return, nothing more and nothing less. How did you query it?

Comment: its not about query, suppose I'm sending a number via variable, then?

Comment: Pass `_ID` that the database has returned

Comment: passing is not problem, please read the question again

Comment: “but it adds contact number and name automatically if i pass them from the database” — what adds them automatically? where? what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: like we save a number in our mobile,and add contact name I want to do that

Comment: I still don't understand what adds the name automatically. You can create a contact without a name simply by not providing one.

Comment: sorry for being silly, i have solved the problem by using intent from the example of android developers guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer of this problem is solved as it is shown in the link  [Modifying Contact](http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/modify-data.html)